# Extract multiple variables by naming convention, for more than two types of naming convention

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract multiple variables that start with certain strings. For this example I'd like to write a code that will extract all variables that start with X1 and Y2.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(X1_1=sample(1:5,10,TRUE),
                 X1_2=sample(1:5,10,TRUE),
                 X2_1=sample(1:5,10,TRUE),
                 X2_2=sample(1:5,10,TRUE),
                 Y1_1=sample(1:5,10,TRUE),
                 Y1_2=sample(1:5,10,TRUE),
                 Y2_1=sample(1:5,10,TRUE),
                 Y2_2=sample(1:5,10,TRUE))
```

I know I can use the following to extract variables that begin with "X1"

```
Vars_to_extract <- c("X1")
tempdf <- df[ , grep( paste0(Vars_to_extract,".*" )  , names(df), value=TRUE)]
  X1_1 X1_2
1    3    5
2    3    4
3    2    1
4    2    2
5    3    3
```

But I need to adapt above code to extract variables multiple variable types, if specified like this

Vars_to_extract <- c("X1","Y2")

I've been trying to do it using an **%in%** with **.*** within the **grep** part, but with little success. I know to I can write the following which is pretty manual, merging each set of variables separately.

```
tempdf <- data.frame(df[, grep("X1.*", names(df), value=TRUE)] , df[, grep("Y2.*", names(df), value=TRUE)] )
  X1_1 X1_2 Y2_1 Y2_2
1    3    5    1    5
2    3    4    1    5
3    2    1    2    3
4    2    2    3    1
5    3    3    4    2
```

However, in real world situation, I often work with lots of variables and would have to do this numerous times. Is it possible to write it in this way using %in% or does I need use a loop? Any help or tips will be gratefully appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `contains` if we want to extract column names that have the substring anywhere in the string

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    select(contains(Vars_to_extract))
```

Or with `matches`, we can use a regex to specify the the string starts (`^`) with the specific substring

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
      select(matches(str_c('^(', Vars_to_extract, ')', collapse="|")))
```

---

With `grep`, we could create a single pattern by `paste` with `collapse = "|"`

```
df[grep(paste0("^(",paste(Vars_to_extract, collapse='|'), ")"), names(df))]
#    X1_1 X1_2 Y2_1 Y2_2
#1     3    5    5    3
#2     3    3    5    5
#3     2    3    3    3
#4     2    1    1    2
#5     3    4    4    5
#6     5    1    1    5
#7     4    1    1    3
#8     1    5    3    2
#9     2    3    4    2
#10    3    2    1    2
```

---

Or another approach is to `startsWith` with `lapply` and `Reduce`

```
df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(Vars_to_extract, startsWith, x = names(df)))]
```

Comment: The variables need to start with the specified variable X1 rather than contain it. as there may be other variables that also have X1 as part of it's name. Contain function would probably pull out a variable named ABCX1

Comment: @H.Cheung Try with the update i.e. using `paste` and `str_c`

Comment: @H.Cheung If you can provide an example where it doesn't work with `paste` that would be great

Comment: I just tested on some of my "real" world data. The methods using grep and reduce, both work. It seems to work. Fantastic. Thanks